# " Writing regular expression to extract keywords from String"

Tags: php, regex

I have a function as stated below : I want to write a php code which will extract the word immediately after keyword ***function***. In this case " ***deletefav($body)***". Similarly i want to extract all keywords which start with ***$body ->*** and end with **)** or **;** . In this case " *userid* and *adid* " After finding function name and keys i want to generate a json request as

***{"method_name":"deletefav","body":{"userid":"","adid":""}}***

( Appending extracted function name and keys ( user id and adid ) as shown above.)

```
function deletefav($body) 

    {

        $userid =  trim($body -> userid);
        $adid =  $body -> adid;
        $deletefav = sprintf("Delete from fav where userid='%d' and adid = '%d'",$userid,$adid);
        DB :: mysql_execute_query($deletefav);
        $returnArray['status']="1";
        $returnArray['message']= "delted from fav";
        return json_encode($returnArray);

    }
```

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte can you please  throw  more light on that

Comment: Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php

Comment: please include the code that you have tried so far